# Problem with Combobox in ExtJS

Tags: combobox, extjs

I am developing a website, which is going to be accessed by an embedded system with a touchscreen interface. In order to provide the data to an ExtJS combobox, the user uses an on-screen keyboard (such as the add-ons  provided by chrome and firefox, which are developed in javascript). When I select the combobox, I can type the first character (the combobox looses the focus when the keyboard button is pressed and then focuses once again when the key in the keyboard is released). When I try to insert the second character, the first one is erased instead of being concatenated to the end.

Is there any way to make sure that the new characters are appended to ones that are already in the combobox?(instead of erasing them).

Any help on this matter would be nice.

Comment: Could you paste your combobox declaration with config options?
I think tweaking them a bit may get you the behaviour you need.

Answer (score 2):

Would need to see code like the previous answerer, but make sure `selectOnFocus` is `false` on the combobox, or else you would be typing over everything for each letter the way you described it.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. SelectOnFocus was true and the text was always selected. Now, the new characters are appended to the end.